# independent scroll column layout in css

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make three independent scroll layout in CSS. The independent columns are not scrolling. If I modify the style then the whole page is scrolling. I need to scroll keep the left and right column static while the middle column only scroll.
HTML

```
<div>
 <div id="nav">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div class="search-container">
        <form action="/action_page.php">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Search Quora" name="search" onfocus="quo(this)">
        </form>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#user"><i class="fas fa-user-circle fa-lg"></i></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <button class="add">Add Question</button>
    </li>
  </ul>
 </div>
 <div class="content">
  <div id="left">
    <h2>Column 1</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
  <div id="middle">
    <h2>Column 2</h2>
    <p>By way of precaution, when all was complete De Rozier made a few short captive excursions, the balloon being fastened to earth by a rope. But all proving satisfactory, he decided to hazard a right away trip on the 21st of November 1783, when he was also to be accompanied by an equally courageous fellow-countryman, the Marquis dArlandes. It would be difficult to conceive a more daring and perilous enterprise than these two brave Frenchmen set themselves. They were to venture, by an untried way, into unknown realms where no mortal had been before; they were to entrust their lives to a frail craft whose capabilities had never yet been tested, and at a giddy height they were to soar aloft with an open fire, which at any moment might set light to the inflammable balloon and hurl them to destruction.</p>
 </div>
  <div id="right">
    <h2>Column 3</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#left{
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  background: blue;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  padding: 0.4em;
}
#right {
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
    background: red;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    padding: 0.4em;
}
#middle {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  background: coral;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  padding: 0.4em;
}
.content{
  padding-top:60px;
  padding-left:20px;
  padding-right:20px;
  height: 100%;
}
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Whats the problem? I used this solution it worked perfectly fine there. https://jsfiddle.net/hr6au65b/
I think there's some issue with content style in CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it by `position:sticky` ..
firstly remove `overflow: hidden;` from `body,html` .. then  add `display:flex` to `.content` class. and add `position:sticky` and `top:0` to `#reght` and `#left` id..

```css
#left{
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  background: blue;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  padding: 0.4em;
   position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  }
#right {
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
    background: red;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    padding: 0.4em;
      position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
#middle {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  background: coral;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  padding: 0.4em;
}
.content{
  padding-top:60px;
  padding-left:20px;
  padding-right:20px;
  height: 100%;
  display:flex;
}
html, body {
    height: 100%;

    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
 <div id="nav">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div class="search-container">
        <form action="/action_page.php">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Search Quora" name="search" onfocus="quo(this)">
        </form>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#user"><i class="fas fa-user-circle fa-lg"></i></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <button class="add">Add Question</button>
    </li>
  </ul>
 </div>
 <div class="content">
  <div id="left">
    <h2>Column 1</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
  <div id="middle">
    <h2>Column 2</h2>
    <p>By way of precaution, when all was complete De Rozier made a few short captive excursions, the balloon being fastened to earth by a rope. But all proving satisfactory, he decided to hazard a right away trip on the 21st of November 1783, when he was also to be accompanied by an equally courageous fellow-countryman, the Marquis dArlandes. It would be difficult to conceive a more daring and perilous enterprise than these two brave Frenchmen set themselves. They were to venture, by an untried way, into unknown realms where no mortal had been before; they were to entrust their lives to a frail craft whose capabilities had never yet been tested, and at a giddy height they were to soar aloft with an open fire, which at any moment might set light to the inflammable balloon and hurl them to destruction.
    t all proving satisfactory, he decided to hazard a right away trip on the 21st of November 1783, when he was also to be accompanied by an equally courageous fellow-countryman, the Marquis dArlandes. It would be difficult to conceive a more daring and perilous enterprise than these two brave Frenchmen set themselves. They were to venture, by an untried way, into unknown realms where no mortal had been before; they were
    t all proving satisfactory, he decided to hazard a right away trip on the 21st of November 1783, when he was also to be accompanied by an equally courageous fellow-countryman, the Marquis dArlandes. It would be difficult to conceive a more daring and perilous enterprise than these two brave Frenchmen set themselves. They were to venture, by an untried way, into unknown realms where no mortal had been before; they were
    
    </p>
 </div>
  <div id="right">
    <h2>Column 3</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is what exactly I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

The containing (i.e. parent) elements of your `content` div also need to have `height: 100%;`. It works in the example fiddle you linked to because the `body` is 100% height, but you have an extra `div` in your example between the body and content.

All you need to do is add `height: 100%;` to the first outer `div`. You can create a class e.g. `height-100pc` with this style:

```
.height-100pc {
  height: 100%;
}
```

...and add it to any parent containers of your `content` div, e.g.:

```
<div class="height-100pc">
   <div id="nav"> ... </div>
   <div ="content"> <!-- Your columns here --> </div>
</div>
```

**Working Example:**

```css
#left {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  background: blue;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0.4em;
}

#right {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  background: red;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0.4em;
}

#middle {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  background: coral;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0.4em;
}

.content {
  padding-top: 60px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  height: 100%;
}

.height-100pc {
  height: 100%;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

*{box-sizing: border-box; }
```

```html
<div class="height-100pc">
  <div id="nav">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <div class="search-container">
          <form action="/action_page.php">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Search Quora" name="search" onfocus="quo(this)">
          </form>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#user"><i class="fas fa-user-circle fa-lg"></i></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <button class="add">Add Question</button>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div id="left">
      <h2>Column 1</h2>
      <p>Some text..</p>
    </div>
    <div id="middle">
      <h2>Column 2</h2>
      <p>By way of precaution, when all was complete De Rozier made a few short captive excursions, the balloon being fastened to earth by a rope. But all proving satisfactory, he decided to hazard a right away trip on the 21st of November 1783, when he
        was also to be accompanied by an equally courageous fellow-countryman, the Marquis dArlandes. It would be difficult to conceive a more daring and perilous enterprise than these two brave Frenchmen set themselves. They were to venture, by an untried
        way, into unknown realms where no mortal had been before; they were to entrust their lives to a frail craft whose capabilities had never yet been tested, and at a giddy height they were to soar aloft with an open fire, which at any moment might
        set light to the inflammable balloon and hurl them to destruction.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="right">
      <h2>Column 3</h2>
      <p>Some text..</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Note that if this div was inside another div, you would have to apply the class to it *as well*. See the examples below to see what works and what doesn't:

```
<!-- This WON'T work: -->
<div>
    <div class="height-100pc">
       <div id="nav"> ... </div>
       <div ="content"> <!-- Your columns here --> </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- This WON'T work: -->
<div class="height-100pc">
    <div>
       <div id="nav"> ... </div>
       <div ="content"> <!-- Your columns here --> </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- This WILL work: -->

<div class="height-100pc">
    <div class="height-100pc">
       <div id="nav"> ... </div>
       <div ="content"> <!-- Your columns here --> </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

FYI, you should use `box-sizing: border-box;` instead of `box-sizing: content-box;` - otherwise the padding is added to the widths and the total width is 100% + padding, so the boxes will wrap.

Comment: Good answer :) .